# Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{kn} f\left ( \dfrac{1}{n+p}\right )$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

Let $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ a differentiable function from the right on $x=0$ and such that $f(0)=0$. Fix $k\in\Bbb R$, calculate  $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{kn} f\left ( \dfrac{1}{n+p}\right ).$$

Someone give me a clue to start doing the exercise that I don't know how to start. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Not rigorous, but you could write $f(x)=f'(0)x+o(x)$ for small $x$, plug this estimation into $f$and you can get the answer. Also, notice that $\int_{1}^{k+1} \mathrm d x/x=\ln (k+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can substract as many $ f(0)$ as we like because they are 0. IE:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\dots f\left(\frac{1}{n+kn}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(0\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-f\left(0\right)+\dots f\left(\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)k}\right)-f\left(0\right) $$
Using the formula for the derivative $$ f'\left(0\right)^{+}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(0+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(0\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} $$
We can get
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{kn}f\left(\frac{1}{n+p}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}f'\left(0\right)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=1}^{nk}\frac{1}{1+\frac{p}{n}} =\\ f'\left(0\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+\dots\frac{1}{1+k}\right)$$
This Riemann sum is known to be $$ f'\left(0\right)\int\limits _{0}^{k}\frac{1}{1+x}dx $$